# Specifying names of columns to be used in a loop R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a df with over 30 columns and over 200 rows, but for simplicity will use an example with 8 columns.

```
X1<-c(sample(100,25))
B<-c(sample(4,25,replace=TRUE))
C<-c(sample(2,25,replace =TRUE))
Y1<-c(sample(100,25))
Y2<-c(sample(100,25))
Y3<-c(sample(100,25))
Y4<-c(sample(100,25))
Y5<-c(sample(100,25))
df<-cbind(X1,B,C,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

I wrote a function that melts the data generates a plot with X1 giving the x-axis values and faceted using the values in B and C.

```
plotdata<-function(l){
    melt<-melt(df,id.vars=c("X1","B","C"),measure.vars=l)
    plot<-ggplot(melt,aes(x=X1,y=value))+geom_point()
    plot2<-plot+facet_grid(B ~ C)
    ggsave(filename=paste("X_vs_",l,"_faceted.jpeg",sep=""),plot=plot2)
}
```

I can then manually input the required Y variable

```
plotdata("Y1")
```

I don't want to generate plots for all columns. I could just type the column of interest into plotdata and then get the result, but this seems quite inelegant (and time consuming). I would prefer to be able to manually specify the columns of interest e.g. "Y1","Y3","Y4" and then write a loop function to do all those specified.

However I am new to writing for loops and can't find a way to loop in the specific column names that are required for my function to work. A standard for(i in 1:length(df)) wouldn't be appropriate because I only want to loop the user specified columns

Apologies if there is an answer to this is already in stackoverflow. I couldn't find it if there was.

Comment: Try `for (x in c("Y1","Y3","Y4")) plotdata(x)`. The index variable doesn't have to be numeric.

Comment: for(x in c("Y1","Y3","Y4")){plotdata(x)} works a treat! Thanks!

Comment: Go ahead and that up as an answer yourself, so you can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Roland for providing the following answer:

Try

```
for (x in c("Y1","Y3","Y4")) {plotdata(x)}
```

The index variable doesn't have to be numeric